# how can i make my query optimize to reduce the execution time

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

Please let me how i can reduce the query to reduce the execution time .

```
SELECT 
   CASE
      WHEN MONTH(QBQ_DATEJOUR) = 1  AND QBQ_VALAXECT1 = [AXE1]  THEN
         (QBQ_CAHISTO+(QBQ_CAHISTO*([EV1]))/100) 
      WHEN MONTH(QBQ_DATEJOUR) = 2  AND QBQ_VALAXECT2 = [AXE2] THEN
         (QBQ_CAHISTO+(QBQ_CAHISTO*([EV2]))/100)
      WHEN MONTH(QBQ_DATEJOUR) = 3 AND [EV3] <> 0  THEN
         (QBQ_CAHISTO+(QBQ_CAHISTO*([EV3]))/100) 
      WHEN MONTH(QBQ_DATEJOUR) = 4 THEN
         (QBQ_CAHISTO+(QBQ_CAHISTO*([EV4]))/100) 
      ELSE QBQ_CAHISTO
   END  AS NVPREVU,
   MONTH(QBQ_DATEJOUR) AS MOISP
FROM QBPCUBETMP
WHERE QBQ_CODESESSION = [SESSION]
AND QBQ_VALAXECT1 = [AXE1]
AND QBQ_VALAXECT2 = [AXE2]
```

How can i make this optimize. Please share some alternative

Comment: . . tag your question with the database you are using.  The table layout, existing indexing, and an execution plan would also help.

Comment: Start with the WHERE clause.

Comment: instead of using case can we use any function to call the value

Comment: Yes you can use function, but that will not help you. You should provide more information. The best approach is to press CTRL+M in SSMS and paste the execution plan as XML.

Comment: Do you have an index on QBQ_CODESESSION, QBQ_VALAXECT1, and QBQ_VALAXECT2 ?

Comment: You're best bet is likely going to be a filtered covering index.

Comment: FYI, you might want to start accepting answers if they solve your issue. I see you haven't accepted any answers to your questions; that is fine if they don't resolve your question, but poor etiquette and will likely lead people to ignore your questions.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make it easy for us to help you - by posting the table definitions and execution plan. Otherwise, my best answer is "sacrifice to the ancient gods of databases".

Comment: Posting a broken (sort of) query without telling what you are trying to do will not help us help you.  Sample input?  Expected output?  Table structure?  Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I apologies you all for not responding on time.

Comment: I don't have index in my field

Answer (score 1):

Firstly ask your DBA to add, refresh or rebuild indexes to make sure your DB's are running as clean as possible a good index can take a query from 5 minutes to 1 second.

If you are managing your own Databases take a look at [articles online](https://www.sqlshack.com/query-optimization-techniques-in-sql-server-tips-and-tricks/) to help with query optimisation.

There are a lot of factors including the power of the server, RAM, etc beyond indexes so it might be more a case (excuse the pun) of asking for more power/ram.

Comment: Does this even produce a different plan? CTEs are more about syntax and readability than anything else; I would surely not consider them as something in my 'performance toolkit'. In this case I think it makes the query unnecessary 'complex'?! That said, if you can achieve better readability by using CTEs this  indeed may put you on the road to a better query... (PS: And yes, I know you can make a recursive CTE which goes beyond 'just syntax', but that's not applicable here)

Comment: @deroby CTEs are much more than readability, but in fact you're right this doesn't alter the execution plan so I've removed that part of the answer. How would you suggest improving performance here?

Comment: I'd love to hear what (non-recursive) CTE's do more than say subqueries/derived views, but that seems rather off topic. As for performance, a covering index probably will help out quite a bit but we're getting (too) little information here to give a well-founded answer..  =(

Answer (score 1):

I would start by making sure you have created the index:

```
create index ix1 on qbpcubetmp (qbq_codesession, qbq_valaxect1, qbq_valaxect2)
```

Comment: I wonder if having an equal condition between two fields (I'm presuming [SESSION] etc are other columns, I don't see how this would compile otherwise) would benefit from this. Adding SESSION, AXE1 and AXE2 to the index (either as index fields or INCLUDEd) might help I guess, especially if the original table is very "wide". Off course, if [SESSION], [AXE1] and [AXE2] are placeholders for values (of fields from another table that's not shown) then the proposed index is going to be a big step forward.

Comment: @deroby What you are considering is the concept of "covering indexes" (with or without extra columns). A covering index will be faster than a simple one, like the one I included in this question, since it will avoid the "secondary index lookup syndrome" SQL Server suffers from (as well as MySQL InnoDB). How much faster? It could be a bit faster or just marginally faster. We also need to consider a covering index has its drawbacks.

Comment: I agree, I'm simply wondering if (and that remains a big if as the original question isn't overly clear) we assume that [SESSION] etc are columns too, the proposed index will be considered by the optimizer in any way; I guess it would rather do a table scan than use the proposed `idx1`... And indeed, there is no such a thing as a free lunch =)